# epplus for generating excel using greater than and less than

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I am using epplus for Excel. how can use `greater than` and `less than`
condition for showing debit and credit value with `dr` and `cr`.

- if value is `-123456` I want to show it like this: `₹1,23,456 DR`
- if value is `123456` I want to show it like this:`₹1,23,456 CR`

I'm using `Style.Numberformat.Format = "₹ #,###.00"` but it's showing results this way: `-₹1,23,456`. How can I make it to append `cr` and `dr`?

Comment: I edited the question to improve English and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
Style.Numberformat.Format = "₹ #,###.00 \"CR\";₹ #,###.00 \"DR\""
```

Comment: @amitjain I am not sure what you mean.  The above format will imply a condition that if > 0 put CR; if < 0 put DR.  Do you mean you want to use a different number besides 0?